# NodeJS double negate ternary operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

I am using ternary operator in NodeJS below shown

```
let err = {a: 10, message: 0}
const error = !!err.message ? err.message : err;
```

But above code is showing eslint error for double negation how to solve this ? below alternative is same as above

```
const error = err.message ? err.message : err;
```

Comment: Your below code looks like what you should be doing, there's no need to cast to boolean with the conditional operator, is there an error when using it?

Comment: `0` is falsy already, there is no need to `!!`.

Answer (score 6):

There's no actual need to use the `!!` - this code is what you want:

```
const error = err.message ? err.message : err;
```

If you really wanted to check against a Boolean rather than the pure value:

```
const error = Boolean(err.message) ? err.message : err;
```

Also note that what you're doing - if `err.message` is truthy, use it, or use `err` - is the exact use case of the logical OR operator `||`:

```
const err = err.message || err;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the conditional operator entirely if you want - if `err.message` is falsey, just alternate with `err`:

```
const error = err.message || err;
```